# Why were .tex files lost while .synctex.gz files created. How to recover .tex files?

Tags: syntax

Today I found that most of my .tex files created or modified between July 2019 and last week are gone, so are .pdf files produced by these .tex files.  Instead,  corresponding  .synctex.gz files are created.  These files were in different folders of various  levels created and stored in my MacBook Pro,  with Big Sur OS.    I have used TexShop. I have never used SyncTex. When I check the preference of TexShop, I do notice that the sync method of typesetting is listed as SyncTex.

On the other hand, other files such as  .aux files, .log files,  .blg files, .bbl files,  .out files are still in the folders.

What could be the problem? How to recover .tex files?

I cleaned some of my files one week ago, basically some word files and pdf files not related.   Maybe I deleted some system files by accident,  I am not sure.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking the data available in log and temporary files like `.log`, `.blg`, `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.synctex.gz` is not enough to recover the complete `.tex` file. If the PDF file is also gone, chances are extremely slim that you can recover anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What could be  the reason this happened? How can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. For most people the problem is usually that their editor crashed when it tries to write the `.tex` file. (Usually the file isn't gone in those cases, it is just empty or appears to be empty.) But you report that all of your `.tex` and `.pdf` files are gone, which to me sounds an overly eager clean-up tool.

Comment: Thanks, I will tried to recover it by downloading a Data Recovery Software.  Hope it would work.